# How to access Netsuite Project (recordtype=job) using SuiteAnalytics Connect?

Tags: project, netsuite, jobs

How can I access Netsuite projects (recordtype=job) using Suiteanalytics Connect to create queries?
I'm not able to find the records into these tables:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the projects you need to do as follows:

```
select * from customers where customer_id='xxx';
```

Note: customer_id is the internal id of the Project record.